# How to check a varying range of indexes in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array that contains some data. Each block of data is separated by an empty line, and the size of the block varies. How would I go about checking each block to see if it contained the values I need. Here is my current code that handles this. (This doesn't work because it will always check 7 lines)

```
    input = ["ecl:gry pid:860033327 eyr:2020 hcl:#fffffd",
    "byr:1937 iyr:2017 cid:147 hgt:183cm",
    "",
    "iyr:2013 ecl:amb cid:350 eyr:2023 pid:028048884",
    "hcl:#cfa07d byr:1929",
    "",
    "hcl:#ae17e1 iyr:2013",
    "eyr:2024",
    "ecl:brn pid:760753108 byr:1931",
    "hgt:179cm",
    "",
    "hcl:#cfa07d eyr:2025 pid:166559648",
    "iyr:2011 ecl:brn hgt:59in"];   


 
        var byr = false;
        var iyr = false;
        var eyr = false;
        var hgt = false;
        var hcl = false;
        var ecl = false;
        var pid = false;
    
        var numberOfLines = 1;
        
        if (input[arrayIndex+1].charAt(0) == ""){
        numberOfLines = 1;
        } else if (input[arrayIndex+2].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 2;
        } else if (input[arrayIndex+3].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 3;
        } else if (input[arrayIndex+3].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 3;
        } else if (input[arrayIndex+4].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 4;
        } else if (input[arrayIndex+5].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 5;
        } else if (input[arrayIndex+6].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 6;
        }
          else if (input[arrayIndex+7].charAt(0) == ""){
            numberOfLines = 7;
        }    
        if (input[arrayIndex].includes("byr:") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("byr:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("byr:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("byr:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("byr:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("byr:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("byr:")) {
                byr = true;
            } else { byr = false; }
            if (input[arrayIndex].includes("iyr") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("iyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("iyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("iyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("iyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("iyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("iyr:")) {
                iyr = true;
            } else { iyr = false; }
            if (input[arrayIndex].includes("eyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("eyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("eyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("eyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("eyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("eyr:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("eyr:")) {
                eyr = true;
            } else { eyr = false; }
            if (input[arrayIndex].includes("hgt:") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("hgt:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("hgt:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("hgt:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("hgt:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("hgt:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("hgt:")) {
                hgt = true;
            } else { hgt = false; }
            if (input[arrayIndex].includes("hcl:") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("hcl:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("hcl:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("hcl:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("hcl:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("hcl:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("hcl:")) {
                hcl = true;
            } else { hcl = false; }
            if (input[arrayIndex].includes("ecl:") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("ecl:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("ecl:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("ecl:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("ecl:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("ecl:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("ecl:")) {
                ecl = true;
            } else { ecl = false; }
            if (input[arrayIndex].includes("pid:") || input[arrayIndex + 1].includes("pid:") || input[arrayIndex + 2].includes("pid:") || input[arrayIndex + 3].includes("pid:") || input[arrayIndex + 4].includes("pid:") || input[arrayIndex + 5].includes("pid:") || input[arrayIndex + 6].includes("pid:")) {
                pid = true;
            } else { pid = false; }

    if (byr && iyr && eyr && hgt && hcl && ecl && pid) {
        console.log("True");
    } else {
        console.log("False");
    }
```

Comment: please add some data `input` and the wanted result of it.

Comment: You need to learn to write loops instead of writing the same test 7 times with a different index.

Comment: `.charAt()` will never return an empty string, it always returns 1 character.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to create an object with all your fields might be easier:

```js
const inputStr = `ecl:gry pid:860033327 eyr:2020 hcl:#fffffd
byr:1937 iyr:2017 cid:147 hgt:183cm

iyr:2013 ecl:amb cid:350 eyr:2023 pid:028048884
hcl:#cfa07d byr:1929

hcl:#ae17e1 iyr:2013
eyr:2024
ecl:brn pid:760753108 byr:1931
hgt:179cm

hcl:#cfa07d eyr:2025 pid:166559648
iyr:2011 ecl:brn hgt:59in`;

const input = inputStr.split('\n\n'); // Split on empty lines
const fields = ['byr', 'iyr', 'eyr', 'hgt', 'hcl', 'ecl', 'pid'];

input.forEach(passport => {
  const res = fields.reduce((res, field) => ({
    ...res, // Keep the previous fields
    [field]: passport.includes(field) // Add the current one
  }), {});

  console.log(JSON.stringify(res)); // {"byr": true, "iyr": true, ...}

  const allFieldsArePresent = Object.values(res).every(val => val);
  console.log(allFieldsArePresent);
});
```

When writing code, always try to think "DRY" (Don't Repeat Yourself). If you find yourself repeating things over and over, it's a big *code-smell*, there is a 99.999% chance it could be written in a shorter, more maintainable way.